# Check If Property Exists On Object C#

Tags: c#

I am using a wmi call to get some info shown below

```
   var queryObj = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");
            var vmSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(queryObj);

        foreach (ManagementObject MO in vmSearcher.Get())
        {
            if (MO.GetType().GetProperty("AddressWidth") != null)
            {
                Value = MO["AddressWidth"].ToString();
            }

            //TRY TO FORCE TO NOT EXIST TO TEST..IS THIS THE WAY TO FORCE A 
            //PROPERTY OUT??
            MO["CurrentClockSpeed"] = null;

            if (MO.GetType().GetProperty("CurrentClockSpeed") != null)
            {
                Value2 = MO["CurrentClockSpeed"].ToString();
            }
         }
```

The problem is some machines have some properties and others have other properties

How do I check if a property exists or not on a machine? 
What I have isn't working

What I ultimately want is to simply print out properties of my choosing (like the on in the code sample) if they exist

Comment: Have you tried querying the [`Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementbaseobject.properties?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Management_ManagementBaseObject_Properties) collection on the `ManagementObject`?

Comment: What do you mean by *force a property out*? I'm sorry, but this question doesn't make sense to me. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `MO` is a type of dictionary. So wouldn't it be better if you use `MO.ContainsKey(x)` instead?

Comment: @Crimson7 - You are wrong. `MO` is (correctly) declared as a `ManagementObject`, not a `Dictionary`. Not sure where the `Dictionary` assumption came from.

Comment: How about using `MO.Properties.Remove(x)` for unsetting the data, and using`MO.Properties.Contains(x)` for checking if the data exists or not?

Answer (score 2):

```
   public static object TryGetProperty(ManagementObject wmiObj, string propertyName)
        {
            object retval;
            try
            {
                retval = wmiObj.GetPropertyValue(propertyName);
            }
            catch (System.Management.ManagementException ex)
            {
                retval = null;
            }
            return retval;
        }
```